# Keep LXPanel on top in Openbox

Tags: x11, lxde

I'm configuring a Raspberry Pi as a set-top box. I can get Firefox and Chromium to start up in full screen mode. But I want the LXPanel (configured to auto-hide) to respond when the browser is running in full screen mode. However either it does not activate when I move my mouse to the bottom of the screen or it is popping up underneath the browser window (same with both browsers).

**Update**
I've noticed that while running in normal window mode, with the window slightly smaller than full screen, lxpanel expands underneath the browser window.

Note that the panel does not have the usual window decoration so I can't right click. I believe that it should be possible to create an openbox rc file - if only I new the [application class](http://icculus.org/pipermail/openbox/2013-May/007941.html).

**update2**

Apparently the application class (and lots of other X attributes) can be found with xprop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default build of openbox/pixel comes with an rc file (/home/pi/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml) which already has an application entry for lxpanel.

```
...
  <applications>
    <application name="panel">
    <skip_taskbar>yes</skip_taskbar>
    <layer>above</layer>
    </application>
    <application name="panel" type="dock">
    <layer>below</layer>
  </application>
 ,,,
```

All it needs is for "below" to be changed to "above".

However with both Chromium (56) and Firefox (51) when in "full screen" mode, the panel is still hidden by the browser.

For the benefit of anyone simply trying to keep a different window on top, the process is described in the [OpenBox wiki](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Applications). Note that both obxprop and xprop are included in the standard installation.

Firefox is not in the standard installation - and you need to jump through some hoops to get it working. Google for options.